# Custom price is not getting calculated on cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, magento2.2.2, custom-prices

I am setting up the custom price with some calculation during add to cart and update cart.

I am using following code to add custom price

```
$fPrice = 39.1467 // after calculation 
$qty = 24;
$item->setCustomPrice($fPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($fPrice);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Magento 2 calculating the row subtotal with this price and 24 quantity = $939.60 instead it should be $939.52. I have checked into the database and found that it is calculating with `$fprice = 39.15` but I want to calculate with  `$fPrice = 39.1467` to correct the subtotal value.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Database item row :** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$totalItems = count($items);
if ($totalItems != 0) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if($item->getProductId() == $productId){
            $item->setData('qty', $qty);
            $item->addOption(array(
                   'code' => 'additional_options',
                   'value' => $this->_serialize->serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));
            $item->setCustomPrice($fPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($fPrice);
            $item->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** The price and qty will be set in all products cart, you need to get the values dynamically for all products.

Comment: My concern is, row total price is based on 39.15 while I have set custom price is 39.1467. I have checked into the database too. Price is saving correctly in db.

Comment: By default magento consider 2 decimal places, So in frontend your price look like that.